# Custom UIButton + subviews = no events

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uibutton

Basically I have a custom UIButton and this custom button contains subviews. If I add those subviews to my UIButton, then the button stops responding to event changes. I.e if I tap on it it doesn't respond to the selector. I have everything set as `userInteractionEnabled`. I also tried adding touchbegan and this is working. If I remove those subviews, the UIButton works again.

How Do I get the tap events from the button?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The subviews should have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`.  What is happening here is that the subviews are getting the touch events instead of the UIButton. If that doesn't work another option is to override `hitTest:withEvent:` in your custom UIButton so that it always returns itself and does not ask its subviews if they should handle the event.  See the [UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were right, i should not have userinteraction as enabled.

Comment: I cannot tell how *how many times* this has borked me. I keep thinking it needs to be reversed. I'm gonna go play with an etch-a-sketch now.

Comment: Thanks - for my subclassed button userInteractionEnabled didn't work but the hitTest approach did: - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return self;
}