# General XCode UI Question

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

Simple question: If I have a UIButton and fill it with different subviews (UIViews, let's say) to make a grid or a collage type thing or whatever, will the button still work even if it's covered in other views?

Comment: Your answer is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725254/custom-uibutton-subviews-no-events.

Comment: So as long as I have userInteractionEnabled set to NO, I should be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are added as **subviews** to the UIButton (being a subclass of UIView),

```
[myButton addSubview: collageElementSubview];
```

there should be no problem (although I would disable user interaction on the subviews just to be safe).